# I want a credit card transaction to go to different accounts based on the product the user purchases

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

My web site processes different types of transactions.  One may be for a service and another for a product.  I have different bank accounts for the different types of transactions.  Is it possible to deposit money via my gateway into different accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could setup logic within your code to use entirely separate PayPal accounts depending on the products/services being purchased.

Another option would be to add both bank accounts to a single PayPal account and just transfer the amounts to each one accordingly.  If you're using financial software of any kind to manage orders you should be able to easily generate a report showing you how much you should send to each bank account.